# Character.isDigit() error: no suitable method found for isDigit(String)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Kepp getting an error when using Character.isDigit()

I've looked it up elsewhere and tested it fine there but I keep running into this error here.

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean hasDigit;
  String passCode;

  hasDigit = false;
  passCode = scnr.next();

  hasDigit = Character.isDigit(passCode);

  if (hasDigit) {
     System.out.println("Has a digit.");
  }
  else {
     System.out.println("Has no digit.");
  }
```

Expect true or false depending on scanner input. Keep getting this error thrown at me:

```
CheckingPasscodes.java:12: error: no suitable method found for isDigit(String)
  hasDigit = Character.isDigit(passCode);
                      ^
method Character.isDigit(char) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to char)
method Character.isDigit(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to int)
```

Comment: @Villat - that is different - that refers to the developer trying to call `String.isDigit()` which doesn't exist. This problem is that `Character.isDigit(String)` doesn't exist. But `Character.isDigit(char)` does.

Comment: @Jason you're right, I misread the question. Flag removed.

Comment: It is not 'throwing errors'. It is *printing* a *compiler error.* You are calling a non-existent method, and the compiler is telling you so. Read the message.

Answer (score 7):

The method `Character.isDigit()` takes a `char` as input - you are trying to pass it a `String`.

The error described what the problem is:

> argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to char

Answer (score 1):

The error is that `hasDigit = Character.isDigit(passCode);`
  `Character.isDigit()` expects a character as an argument but you passing String.
So correct this convert the String to char.
you can try

```
     Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  boolean hasDigit;
  char passCode;

  hasDigit = false;
  passCode =  scnr.next().charAt(0);

  hasDigit = Character.isDigit(passCode);

  if (hasDigit) {
     System.out.println("Has a digit.");
  }

  else {
     System.out.println("Has no digit.");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner.next method will return whole tokens (usually words) from the input stream.  These words are Strings.  The Character.isDigit function requires a char as input, not a String.

You could loop over the word, get each letter as a char and test them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < passCode.length(); i++){
    char c = passCode.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        hasDigit = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me. I set each specified index in the string to a character value using charAt(). From there I created an if statement that would set hasDigit to true if any of the char variables had a number, using Character.isDigit()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYJo3.png)

Comment: Hi Rosaurio, it would very helpful if you could paste your solution as code instead of a link to an image (would easier to read from your answer, possibility to copy).